# Non-multiply covered map in $D^2$ is bijective in the interior

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a map $w:D^2\rightarrow S^2$ that is $J$-holomorphic. We say that it's multiply covered it there exists a map $f:D^2\rightarrow D^2$ of degree $|d|>1$ and a map $w':D^2\rightarrow S^2$ such that $w=w'\circ f$.

Now I have seen a result saying that if $w$ is not multiply covered then it's bijective in the interior of $D^2$. I have tried proving this going by contradiction and trying to create the actual map but I got nowhere.
Does anyone know if this is actually true and how can we prove it?

Also could we generalize this for manifolds , or is it specific to this example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, include a reference to the source of the claim.

Comment: The reference is that paper floer cohomology of lagrangian intersections and pseudo holomorphic disks 2 @MoisheKohan

Comment: What do you mean by the degree of a map from $D^2$ to itself?

Comment: You should update your question by providing precise reference and defining the terms you are using. In the present form, the question is too unclear. With one  interpretation, the claim is simply false.